# Using loops to extract coordinates, match them and write to file

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply, sapply

I am trying to use `for` loops (or the `apply` function as an alternative) to extract coordinates from a data.frame, search for the closest point within the E-OBS [gridded dataset](https://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/download.php#datafiles), extract the temperature-data for time x1-x2 and write it to another excel file.

While the code works to extract single data points, I seem unable to include this code within a loop and to add the results potentially next to the input-coordinates.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)

#Coordinates
    df
       ID    site                 E        N
1       1   site_place_date1  7.558758 47.81004
2       2   site_place_date2  7.582749 47.63411
3       3   site_place_date3  7.607968 48.01475
4       4   site_place_date4  7.644660 47.67139
       ...     ...   ...              ...`
```

Set coordinates of target point MANUALLY:

```
lon <- 7.558758  # longitude of location                
lat <- 47.81004 # latitude  of location

#Mean daily temperature
    ncin <- nc_open("tg_0.25deg_reg_v17.0.nc")
      print(ncin)
      t <- ncvar_get(ncin,"time")
      tunits <- ncatt_get(ncin,"time","units")nt <- dim(t)
      nt
      obsoutput <- ncvar_get(ncin, 
                       start= c(which.min(abs(ncin$dim$longitude$vals -   lon)), # look for closest long
                                which.min(abs(ncin$dim$latitude$vals -  lat)),  # look for closest lat
                                1),
                       count=c(1,1,-1))
      DataMeanT <- data.frame(DateN= t, MeanDailyT = obsoutput)
      nc_close(ncin)
      head(DataMeanT)


#check if there are NAs =999
    summary(DataMeanT)

    Data = DataMeanT
    Data$Date = as.Date(Data$DateN,origin="20000-01-01")
    Data$Year = format(Data$Date,"%Y")
    Data$Month = format(Data$Date,"%m")
    head(Data)
    Data$YearMonth = format(Data$Date, format="%Y-%b")

    Data_annual = aggregate(("T_AnnualMean" = MeanDailyT) ~ Year,data = Data, FUN = mean,na.action = na.pass)
    names(Data_annual)[2] <- "AirT"
    head(Data_annual)

#Export table
    write.table(Data_annual, "Site_AirTemp.csv", row.names = FALSE, append = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep = ", ", quote = TRUE)
```

The aim is to run the script as part of a loop for all coordinates in df and to write the temperature data to a new data-table with information on site-ID or alternatively into the next columns of df.

Comment: Can you share what you want your new data to look like?

Comment: Ideally the original datatable with additional columns added for every mean annual temperature measurement from 2000 to 2017. 

`ID site E N 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004...                       
    1 1 site_place_date1 7.558758 47.81004 10.0 10.1 10.2 10.3 ...
    2 2 site_place_date2 7.582749 47.63411 10.0 10.1 10.1 10.2 ...
    3 3 site_place_date3 7.607968 48.01475 10.1 10.2 10.3 10.5 ...
    4 4 site_place_date4 7.644660 47.67139  10.0 10.1 10.2 10.3 ...
       ...  ...  ...  ...`

but also individually as a table with pure temp measurement and site information would be okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap your entire process in a defined method and use an *apply* function to pass in lon/lat coordinates. One great candidate is `mapply` or its wrapper `Map` to iterate elementwise between both vectors of `df$E` and `df$N`. Also, a third argument, `df$site`, is passed into method for unique CSV names as right now the same file will be overwritten.

Below some non-assignment lines such as `head` or `summary` are removed since they do nothing inside a method. Also context managers, `within` and `with` are used to avoid repetition of `Data$` for more streamlined data manipulation. The `Map` call writes to file AND builds a list of aggregated data frames for use later.

**Function**

```
my_function <- function(lon, lat, site) {    
    # Mean daily temperature
    ncin <- nc_open("tg_0.25deg_reg_v17.0.nc")
      print(ncin)
      t <- ncvar_get(ncin,"time")
      tunits <- ncatt_get(ncin,"time","units")nt <- dim(t)

      # look for closest lon and lat
      obsoutput <- ncvar_get(ncin, 
                             start = c(which.min(abs(ncin$dim$longitude$vals - lon)),
                                      which.min(abs(ncin$dim$latitude$vals - lat)),
                                      1),
                             count = c(1,1,-1))

      DataMeanT <- data.frame(DateN = t, MeanDailyT = obsoutput)
    nc_close(ncin)    

    Data <- within(DataMeanT, {
               Date <- as.Date(DateN, origin="2000-01-01")
               Year <- format(Date,"%Y")
               Month <- format(Date,"%m")
               YearMonth <- format(Date, format="%Y-%b")
            })

    Data_annual <- with(Data, aggregate(list("AirT" = MeanDailyT), list(Year=Year),
                                        FUN = mean, na.action = na.pass))    
    # Export table
    write.table(Data_annual, paste0("Site_AirTemp_", site, "_.csv"), row.names=FALSE,
                append = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep = ", ", quote = TRUE)

    # SAVE AGGREGATED DATA FRAME
    return(Data_annual)
}
```

**Call**

```
# ITERATE THROUGH EACH LON/LAT PAIR ELEMENTWISE
df_list <- Map(my_function, df$E, df$N, df$site)

# df_list <- mapply(my_function, df$E, df$N, df$site, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)    # EQUIVALENT CALL
```

Comment: Wow, that actually makes sense. Thank you so much. Actually, it did not work, but making a minor adjustment: 

`DataMeanT <- data.frame(DateN = t, MeanDailyT = obsoutput) nc_close(ncin) Data=DataMeanT Data$Date=as.Date(Data$DateN,origin="2000-01-01") Data$Year=format(Data$Date,"%Y") Data$Month=format(Data$Date,"%m") Data$YearMonth=format(Data$Date, format="%Y-%b")` 

and it works now!

Comment: Whoops! I kept the `$` inside `within`, try it again and avoid those `Data$ <-` lines. See update.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do:

```
library(raster)
b <- brick("tg_0.25deg_reg_v17.0.nc")
e <- extract(b, df[, c('E', 'N')])
```